# What happen if an electron meets another electron?

Tags: matter

A person give me an idea for my physical problem, and I think the answer of this question would be the next step for its answer

I only want to know what they are doing with each other if they meet each other (I know that they will not annihilate each other )

Thanks for all helpful questions.

Comment: Please provide the context for your problem so your question can be be better understood. It's currently too vaguely described.

Comment: My main "problem" is the following question: Why is in the universe more matter than antimatter?  I want to know how the electrons interact if they meet each other.

Comment: @antimatter if that is your real question, then edit your posted question so that it actually asks that.... You won't get very far on this website by beating around the bush.

Comment: Is the question not understandable or top unspecific?

Comment: answered here? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/64628/what-happens-in-electron-electron-collisions

Comment: Maybe just be more specific about what the electrons are doing...Are they in a solid? Electron gas? Isolated? If so, are they moving towards each other? Are they far away from each other?

Comment: You hope to understand one of the hardest unanswered questions in physics from the answer to a disarmingly simple question. That is quite naive.

Answer (score 1):

Two electrons will simply repel each other.

Comment: Also, Electrons are fundamental so they do not break up in a collider for example.  (Protons do!)